# How does C programs know the size of a string given a pointer to char?

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I would like to understand why this code works:

```
void open_image(const char *filename)
{
    char *ImageName = filename;
    printf("%s", ImageName);
}

const char image_name[] = "image.jpg";
open_image(image_name);
```

it prints "image.jpg" as wanted, but I don't know how the program knows the length of the string.

The program knows the size of the string image_name as it is computed during compilation.
But in the open_image function, how does the printf function knows the length of this string as it is only given the pointer ImageName created at runtime?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the chapter on strings in a C tutorial? This will almost certainly be one of the first things it explains.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I have forgotten this fundamental property of strings ...

Answer (score 0):

In C a string (array of char) is always terminated by the "terminator" character `'\0'`, so you can get the length of the array by checking each character until you find it.

Here's a simple solution:

```c
int i = 0;
char ch;
do
{
  ch = arr[i];
  i++;
} while(ch != '\0');
printf("String length: %d\n", i-1); // This will give the string length
printf("Total length of the array: %d\n", i); // This will give the array full length, including the terminator character.
```

Probably the best way to get a char array length is to import the `string.h` library which exposes the `strlen()` function.
However, it's always useful to learn how things actually work at low-level, especially when learning C). **`:-)`**

Comment: Entering the loop is dicey when `c` is uninitialised.

Comment: This will never give the size of the array. It can give the length of the string. The edit doesn't improve.

Comment: _"including the terminator character"_ - no - and why are you involving a new (uninitialized) variable? `int len; for(len = 0; arr[len] != '\0'; ++len) {}` would be enough.

Comment: @WeatherVane I got something urgent right while I was replying, that's why I tried to fix it quickly. I edited the post btw...

Comment: @TedLyngmo you're right, I edited the reply and used a do {}while; but the result should be the same. (Just with one more variable)

Comment: @mikyll98 The result after the edit is not the same as before. Now it _does_ include the terminator - and you're now not reading `ch` when it has an indeterminate value as before. That's good.

Comment: `int` is the wrong type. t should be `size_t`